# Sharing data between 2 services

Tags: angular

I have 2 different services and I want one service to know an instance of the other service but I need the instance to come as singleton.
All the material I've read so far has been about sharing data between components and not between services.

Comment: Should be able to just import one service into the other just as you'd do it with a component.

Answer (score 0):

If you use in your service file definition:

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})
```

then service will be a singleton for your application. For sharing data it's good to use rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of the injection mechanism. When setting an @Injectable decorator for a class, Angular will try to create or get instances for corresponding types in the injector for the current execution chain.

service1.ts

```
 @Injectable()
    export class Service1 {
      constructor(private service2:Service2) {}

      getData() {
        return this.service2.getData();
      }
    }
```

Service2.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class Service2 {

  getData() {
    return [
      { message: 'message1' },
      { message: 'message2' }
    ];
  }
}
```